How to return an empty array through `present` using Grape
I have the following logic for my endpoint:
get 'collection' do
     ...

   collection_of_items = [ OpenStruct.new(**attributes), OpenStruct.new(**attributes), ...  ] – the array is dynamic depending on how many items I can fetch but the important part – it's an array

   present(collection_of_items, with: Entities::MyEntity)
end

So normally here I'd pass my collection_of_items and it returns an array of objects for my endpoint.
The edge case is when collection_of_items consists of OpenStrucks that don't fit MyEntity. How do I return just an empty array or nil via this:
present(collection, with: Entities::MyEntity) 

?
Because right now it returns {"my_entity"=>#<Entities::MyEntity:0xd1d8>} and I want {"collection"=>[]}
And I don't understand how Grape makes present to return an array of those entities under the hood, if anyone could explain, please?

It's OpenStruct as in a Struct but with dynamic properties.

Briefly, I'm fetching some data from an external API and if an item is available they return – let's say – the price and if it's not available on their side they don't return that attribute at all. And MyEntity exposes price but it's possible that there are no items available at all so in that case MyEntity can't match the attribute so I want an empty array to be returned on my side. Perhaps that's a little clearer

@unnamed_road in that case it has nothing to do with grape you will need to filter that data first. Something as simple as fetched_objects.reject { |attributes| attributes.compact.empty?} should work based on your current question

Thanks @engineersmnky! I'll try this approach

If collection is an empty Array it will be represented as an empty Array.
present calls Entities::MyEntity.represent in your case so you can see this by simply using
Entities::MyEntity.represent([]).to_json
#=> "[]"

Here is a full Example using Grape::DSL::InsideRoute#present with an Array of objects as well as an empty Array.
require 'grape'
require 'grape-entity'

class MyEntityPresenter < Grape::Entity 
  expose :name 
end 

class MyEntity 
  attr_reader :name 

  def initialize(name:)
    @name = name 
  end 
end 

class Dummy
  include Grape::DSL::InsideRoute

  attr_reader :env, :request, :new_settings

  def initialize
    @env = {}
    @header = {}
    @new_settings = { namespace_inheritable: {}, namespace_stackable: {} }
  end
end

collection = ('A'..'D').map {|name| MyEntity.new(name: name)}

route =  Dummy.new
route.present(collection, with: MyEntityPresenter)
route.body.to_json
#=>"[{\"name\":\"A\"},{\"name\":\"B\"},{\"name\":\"C\"},{\"name\":\"D\"}]"


route =  Dummy.new
route.present([], with: MyEntityPresenter)
route.body.to_json
#=> "[]"


I am really sorry, I've edited the question. The problem lies in those OpenStrucks when they can't map to MyEntity (what I expose doesn't fit what an OpenStruck consists of). so in that case I want an empty array back instead
